# Process to install Virtual Box Guest Additions Virtual Box

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualbox, guest-additions

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Server (guest machine) on VirtualBox having Windows 7 as host machine.

Could you please tell me the whole process to install Virtual Box Guest Additions or provide me with best answer reference link !!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a Windows related question since you need to install them in the host. So seems off topic to me. And ... https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp53491632

Comment: Why -1 for this question ?? Means if anybody is asking the question just give the right answer man !! anyways i got the link

Comment: Dunno. Maybe cuz you should ask this on a windows platform?

Comment: @Rinzwind why on windows platform. I have no issues with host machine. I'm getting problems with virtual box that contains Ubuntu 12.04 server as guest machine .

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried the answer from the link given by you. The answer told me to first install dkms for building external kernel modules but whenever i tried to install dkms it shows the unmet dependencies issue (dkms depends on gcc) & even i tried to install gcc , but again i got the issue E: Package 'gcc' has no installation candidate ..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already downloaded a `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` file to your host filesystem, you should be able to install the image from the VM's `Devices` menu using `Insert Guest Additions CD Image...`

*Note that does not actually install the guest addition components, it just makes the ISO available as a virtual CD.* On Ubuntu Server guest OSes, it does not even mount the virtual CD within the guest system.

Alternatively, you can download the ISO straight into the guest system from the repository, using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

Once you have made the ISO available by one of the above methods, you must mount it somewhere in the filesystem. I am going to assume you want to use mountpoint `/mnt` for that, but you can create a different mountpoint if you wish.

**If you inserted the ISO image as a virtual CD:**

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
```

**If you installed the guest additions ISO package from inside Ubuntu:**

```
sudo mount /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso /mnt
```

Finally, navigate to the mount point and run the installer:

```
cd /mnt

sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but i insert the VirtualBox Guest addition(which is located in C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox of my host machine windows 7)from the devices menu in Virtual Box but i can't see the ISO file in - media/cdrom  !!

Comment: @gurupalsingh on **server** systems you won't see it in `/media/cdrom` unless you manually create that mountpoint and mount it there. If you tried to do that and it failed, then please post any error messages.

Comment: thank man , that worked but with errors ..!!

Comment: I got this error - "The gcc utility was not found.If the following module compilation fails then this could
be the reason & u shud try installing it.Building the main guest additions module..fail !!
(Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find what went wrong)
could not find the X.org or XFree86 Window System, skipping. "